# Feynman-Kac for PIDEs: to jump or not to jump?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following Cauchy problem for a $\mathscr{C}^2$ function $F$ characterized by a PIDE:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
& F_t(t,x)+\alpha(t,x)F_x(t,x)+\frac{1}{2}\beta^2(t,x)F_{xx}(t,x)
\\
&\qquad +\gamma(t)(F(t,x+kx)-F(t,x)-kxF_x(t,x))=0
\\[2pt]
& F(T,x)=f(x)
\end{cases}
\end{align}
for some functions $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $f$ satisfying technical conditions, and where $k\in[-1,1]$.

**To jump...**
A suitable version of the Feynman-Kac theorem would state that the solution $F$ to the Cauchy problem above is given by:
\begin{align}
\tag{1a}
F(t,x)=\mathbb{E}^{t,x}(f(X_T))
\end{align}
where the expectation is taken under a probability measure $\mathbb{P}_1$ such that the process $X$ solves the SDE:
\begin{align}
\tag{1b}
dX_t=\alpha(t,X_t)dt + \beta(t,X_t)dW_t + kX_{t^-}(dN_t-\gamma(t)dt)
\end{align}
where $W$ is a Brownian Motion and $N$ a Poisson process with intensity $\gamma$. Refer to Section 10.2.5 in Jeanblanc, Yor and Chesney (2009).

**... or not to jump**
Now, let us rearrange our PIDE as follows:
\begin{align}
F_t(t,x)+(\alpha(t,x)-\gamma(t)kx)F_x(t,x)+\frac{1}{2}\beta^2(t,x)F_{xx}(t,x)-\gamma(t)F(t,x)=-\gamma(t)F(t,x+kx)
\end{align}
Then another application of the Feyman-Kac theorem would suggest the solution verifies:
\begin{align}
\tag{2a}
F(t,x)=\mathbb{E}^{t,x}\left(e^{-\int_t^T\gamma(s)ds}f(X_T)+\int_t^Te^{-\int_t^s\gamma(u)du}\gamma(s)F(s,(1+k)X_s)ds\right)
\end{align}
where this time the expectation is taken under a measure $\mathbb{P}_2$ where $X$ solves the SDE:
\begin{align}
\tag{2b}
dX_t=(\alpha(t,X_t)-\gamma(t)kX_t)dt + \beta(t,X_t)dW_t
\end{align}

What is striking is in the first application of the theorem, the stochastic process $X$ which characterizes the solution does not jump, while in the second it does; in both cases the compensator term $-\gamma(t)dt$ remains though. This would suggest we can solve such Cauchy problems with PIDE in two possible measures $\mathbb{P}_1$ and $\mathbb{P}_2$. Intuitively, because the solution is an *expectation*, the specific pathwise properties of process $X$ do not matter as long as distributional properties of the random variable within the expectation are preserved. In particular, we can rearrange $(2a)$ again and write $(2b)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\tag{2a'}
F(t,x)=\mathbb{E}^{t,x}\left(f(X_T)+\int_t^T\gamma(s)(F(s,(1+k)X_s)-F(s,X_s))ds\right)
\end{align}
so that the jumps missing from the dynamics of $X$ are explicitly included in the integrand of the expectation. In some cases these two measures should be equivalent, e.g. if $\alpha(t,x)=\alpha x$ and $\beta(t,x)=\beta x$ for $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, provided the initial state $x>0$ and that $k>-1$ then these two measures should be equivalent as the null set for the process $X$ should be $\{X\leq0\}$ in both cases.

**Is there any reference which shows the equivalence between solutions $(1)$ and $(2)$? Can we even say these 2 solutions are equal?**